# Add Queryset to django updateview

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I have an updateview in which a manager can go and edit all the fields for the associate. Looks like this:(requirement is to add associate_mgr in the as a dropdown in the updateview)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5We2D.png)

**views.py**

```
class ReallocationTeam(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
  model = UserDetails
  form_class = ViewEditSample
  def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('UserProfile:index')
```

**forms.py**

```
class ViewEditSample(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = UserDetails
        fields = ['associate_name','client','lob','associate_mgr']
```

The manager should be able to edit the "assciate_mgr" of that associate too.
**models.py**

```
    associate_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    associate_nbr = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    associate_email = models.EmailField()
    associate_department_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    associate_mgr = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    associate_exec = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    associate_org = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    date_of_service = models.CharField(null=True,blank=True,max_length=11)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_exec = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_team_lead = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

but associate_mgr is not a choice field in my db. 
I need to add a dropdown that contains associate_mgr in my UpdateView. How do I go about implementing that?
Should I go about writing a query to get all managers and populate them i a dropdow: like this mgr = UserDetails.objects.filter(is_manager=True) But then how do i store the selected in associate_mgr field in db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override your form field in your `ModelForm` to be a `ChoiceField` with a list of choices: `UserDetails.objects.filter(is_manager=True).values_list('name')`.

```
associate_mgr = forms.ChoiceField(choices=
    UserDetails.objects.filter(is_manager=True).values_list('associate_name', 'associate_name')
)
```

Then the choice will automatically be saved (the 'associate_name' field value).

But it would probably be a better idea to use a `ForeignKey` on your model, rather than a `CharField`. That would enforce the values to be other `UserDetails` rather than just a string.

Comment: hey, thnx  but it thows an error "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Comment: ok, choices needs to be a list of 2-tuples, so change it to the above. You could also use `values_list('id', 'associate_name')` which will display the name but set the value to the id of the manager (but that would only work if your model field is a FK).